# Zend Db_NoRecordExists - checking against multiple columns

Tags: zend-framework, zend-validate, custom-validators

Zend Db_NoRecordExists docs seem to be limited to checking only one column. Is there a way to check multiple keys when validating an entry? For example, I am allowing the same email address for different cities.

here's my current validator:

```
$email->setValidators(array(array('emailAddress'),
                  array('Db_NoRecordExists',false,
                  array(
                    'table'=>'usercities',
                    'field'=>'email',
                  ))));
```

usercities table has two columns:
email varchar(64)
city_id tinyint

I want to be able to check for the combination of these columns. Is this possible? I assume I'll have to create a custom validator. Can it be done without resorting to a custom class?

thanks!

Oji

Answer (score 1):

noup. u have to write custom validator. try to code `App_Validate_Db_Select` which will use `Zend_Db_Select` as input parameter